# How to SetData in a QtableView Cell using pyside

Tags: python, pyside2, qtableview

I'm trying to set a value in a cell in my QtableView. I'm using Pyside2.

```
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, mlist=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._items = [] if mlist == None else mlist
        self._header = []

    def data(self, index, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
           return None
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return self._items[index.row()][index.column()]
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if value is not None and role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            self._items[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            return True
        return False

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
 # skip the irrelevant code #
    Table = QTableView()
    model = TableModel()
    Table.setModel(model)
    row, column = a_function_that_outputs_the_row_and_column_of_the_cell_to_edit()

    self.Table.model().setData(index ?, value)
```

What I'm struggling with is getting to understand how to pass the index as an argument, I have the row and column, any help on how to do that properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `model.index(row, column, parent=None)` (see the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index)) to get the appropriate [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html).
If the model is two dimensional (not a tree view), the parent is not required:

```
model.setData(model.index(row, column), value)
```

Comment: Thanks ! It seems to solve the problem, though, my cell's data doesn't change. I added the line: Table.model().dataChanged.emit() after the setData line, didn't do a thing

any idea please ? 

Thanks again

Comment: @Hamouza It's the *model* that should send the signal, so you should add `self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)` before `return True` in the model.

Comment: Here's my debug result:
I added print(row, column) before Table.model().setData(Table.model().index(row, column), value) line in the Mainwindow class, it prints the right row and column. Then in setData I added print('setting ', value, ' in ', index.row(), ' ', index.column()) before the self._items[index.row()][index.column()] = value, and here, it show me that the index.row = -1 and index.column = -1, so this is the source of the problem. I don't understand why since my row and column that are passed to setdata are correct.
I think it has something to do with the index..

Comment: The code in your question is missing both `rowCount()` and `columnCount()`, have you implemented them?

Comment: yes I did Implement them. I solved the bug by creating the index using the QAbstractItemModel::createIndex instead of QAbstractItemModel::index.

I don't know why what you suggested didn't work for my case. 

Thanks again @musicamante

Comment: Without [minimal but still *fully reproducible* examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to help accurately. For future reference, always ensure to include **all** required code, especially for complex objects like data models: we cannot "guess" what you did in your code but was just missing in the example, and comment threads with "did you do that?"/"yes but I didn't put in the example" are not very useful. Never rush posting a question: ensure it's good and, if its code has to be run, try *that* on your own: if you can't reproduce it, we cannot either.